# Optimize probability of success between k different flows

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I want to find a set of coefficients ($n \in R$) that solve the following optimization problem,

maximize $\prod_{i=1}^k(1-p_i)^{n_i}$    s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^k n_i = N$.

The $p$'s are known positive constants ($p \in (0,1)$). $N$ is some integer ($N>0$).

So far, I've tried the Lagrangian method but for $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{n_1}}$ I get an inter-dependent expression, i.e. $n_1=f(n_2,...,n_k,\lambda)$. Hence, I don't see how to derive $\lambda$ and find tractable expressions for $n_1,...,n_k$ which are purely functions of $\{p_1,...,p_k\}$.

I've also tried to maximize the $\exp(ln(f))$ but I end up with,

$\exp(n_1ln(1-p_1)+n_2ln(1-p_2)+...+n_kln(1-p_k))$

which doesn't seem to improve compared to the previous approach.

Please advise of an analytic (preferable) or numeric method to solve that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $r_i = \ln(1-p_i)$.

You want to maximize $\prod_i (1-p_i)^{n_i}$. $\ln$ is monotonic, so we can instead maximize $\ln(\prod_i (1-p_i)^{n_i})$.

This simplifies to $\sum_i n_i \ln(1-p_i)$. Using my definition of $r_i$, this is $\sum_i n_i r_i$.

You want to maximize this subject to $\sum_i n_i = N$.

This is an LP with a trivial solution: Choose the $i$ corresponding to the largest $r_i$.

(If you don't trust me, you can write the dual of this LP and the answer is clear.)

Thus, the optimum solution to your original problem is to set $n_i=N$ corresponding to the index with the largest value of $\ln(1-p_i)$.

This is also equivalent to the index of the smallest value of $p_i$.

Comment: Agree is possible. I've tried that option before and it did make sense mathematically to me, however, with respect to my problem (of scheduling packets to different streams with different Prob(err) $p_i$) it made no sense at all. It will possibly help me prove the greedy allocation heuristic I am using is also optimal. Cheers!